# Show Last Product Trained by Retail Rep

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Original source table looks like this:

| RetailRep | TrainingDate | ProductName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2021-12-31 | Potato |
| John | 2021-12-12 | Lemon |
| John | 2021-12-10 | Olives |
| Adam | 2022-01-04 | Lemon |
| Adam | 2021-11-29 | Orange |
| Adam | 2021-11-10 | Orange |
| Kathy | 2021-12-14 | Apple |
| Kathy | 2021-12-10 | Orange |

What I want the Matrix visual to look like:

| RetailRep | TrainingDate | ProductName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2021-12-31 | Potato |
| Adam | 2022-01-04 | Lemon |
| Kathy | 2021-12-14 | Apple |

I can get their latest training date by using the "Latest" selection in the "Values" section of the Matrix visual. But when I try doing that with the ProductName then it just summarizes the products by alphabetical order. So for Adam, it will show "Orange" instead of "Lemon". And for Kathy it will show "Orange" instead of "Apple".

I need to show what the last product was that each Retail Rep was trained in.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the following measure:

```
Measure = 
VAR __maxDate = CALCULATE( MAX('Table'[TrainingDate] ) )
VAR __product = CALCULATE( MAX('Table'[ProductName]), 'Table'[TrainingDate] = __maxDate )

Return __product
```

By doing that you should get the expected result:

[image]